# RXjs: combine 2 switchmaps into 1?

Tags: rxjs, pipe

**Context**

- I have an API call in which I receive an object of type IWishResponse
- I need to call a second API call to get info about the 'receiver'
- I need to store the response of the second API (personResponse) in the first one.

**As Is**

With the code below, I can handle the above context.

```js
 this.http$.get<IWishResponse[]>(environment.apiUrl + 'wish/' + wishID)
 .pipe(
    map(wishResponse => wishResponse[0]),
    switchMap(wishResponse => this.peopleService.getPersonById(wishResponse.receiver).pipe(
        switchMap(personResponse => this.convertWishResponse(wishResponse, personResponse) )
    )),
 )
```

**Question**

Although I have a working code, it feels like it's too much code for this kind of problem. What I would like to do:

**Combine all this logic in one switchmap instead of having nested switchMaps? It feels like a lot of redundant code now...**

Bottom line is that I would like to learn a bit more about RXjs by improving my code above.
Thanks for helping me...

Comment: Does `convertWishResponse()` return array or Observable?

Comment: It returns an Observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the chain by pluck and pass the first api result with `map`, and because you are making two dependent async request, you cannot really combine two `switchMap` into one.

```
 this.http$.get<IWishResponse[]>(environment.apiUrl + 'wish/' + wishID)
 .pipe(
    map(wishResponse => wishResponse[0]),
    switchMap(wishResponse => this.peopleService.getPersonById(wishResponse.receiver).pipe(map(person=>[person,wishResponse])),
    switchMap(([personResponse,wishResponse]) => this.convertWishResponse(wishResponse, personResponse) ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this was my first solution, but with this one I encountered another problem :  an error in VScode : `Argument of type 'IWishResponse | Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IWishResponse | IWishResponse'` ... It seems that the types of personResponse and wishResponse aren't handled correctly (or VScode cannot handle it correctly?).

Comment: it is type checking issue. the code should work, maybe you can. try 
`map(person=>[person,wishResponse] as [Person, IWishResponse]`